ReviewedBy Schema Property: Nested or Not Nested inside mainEntityOfPage?
Regarding the ReviewedBy schema property. What is the difference between having it nested inside the mainEntityOfPage property, and having it at the same level of the type: Article type?
For example:
Case 1:
| type: Article
|​ author
    | type: Person
    | id: example.com/authorprofile
    | url: example.com/authorprofile
|​ reviewedBy
    | type: Person
    | id: example.com/authorprofile2
    | url: example.com/authorprofile2

Case 2:
| type: Article
|​ author
    | type: Person
    | id: example.com/authorprofile
    | url: example.com/authorprofile
| mainEntityOfPage
    | reviewedBy
        | type: Person
        | id: example.com/authorprofile2
        | url: example.com/authorprofile2

I extracted a couple of examples from the Google Rich Results test and tried checking the documentation, but I cannot find a clear answer yet.
Thanks!
Note: I am in the process of learning structured data.

as it's a property, it cannot be nested, only type it belongs to can be nested, and it can only be associated with WebPage, not Article: Used on these types
WebPage reviewedBy. See here about mainEntityOfPage. Unless you have some concrete and reproducible example, this post is likely to be closed, see: How do I ask a good question?
